# Angular2 and desktop apps

Tags: angular

I'm reading about Angular on their website here:  https://angular.io/features.html, and I see the following:

> **Cross Platform**
>
> *Progressive web apps* - Use modern web platform capabilities to deliver app-like experiences.
>   High performance, offline, and zero-step installation.
>
> *Native* - Build native mobile apps with strategies from Ionic Framework,
>   NativeScript, and React Native.
>
> *Desktop* - Create desktop-installed apps across Mac, Windows, and Linux using the
>   same Angular methods you've learned for the web plus the ability to
>   access native OS APIs.

What part of Angular is this page talking about when it says that you can "create desktop-installed apps across Mac, Windows, and Linux"?  Does Angular have some built-in ability to generate desktop apps?  Or are they talking about using some 3rd-party framework like e.g. Electron?

Comment: I was under the impression that this simply meant people can run their angular `app` on a desktop... (this is where the `app` term becomes confusing in my opinion)... Everyone seems to be using - as you suggested, Electron - I can find no evidence that this is supported natively by angular2.

Comment: @Zze:  Thanks for the comment.  That was my first impression, but then I noticed that they explicitly say, "Create **desktop-installed** apps across Mac, Windows, and Linux ... **plus the ability to access native OS APIs**".  Sounds like they're really saying true, legit apps running on a desktop OS.  Maybe I'm just reading too much into it.  :-)  I'm evaluating Electron + Angular2 for a project right now, and when I saw that I wondered if I could possibly ditch Electron to simplify my stack.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to code UI for your app in JavaScript. At least it was available for Win8/Win8.1 WindowsStore apps (not sure about other platforms, but I'm pretty sure there are ways to do that). E.g. you can include any JS library into your app. I could be wrong, but per my understanding, when you launch that application, under the covers, it is running from special type of InternetExplorer process. There are many apps like that. For example some pieces of Skype also use IE (e.g. to show ads). As basic example see http://onehungrymind.com/windows-8-and-angularjs/

Google for WinJS

Comment: I've heard of WinJS, and have seen tools for embedding HTML/JS apps in desktop clients (e.g. Electron, which I mentioned in my post), but that isn't really what my question is about.  I am specifically interested in whether or not Angular2 has any *built-in* ability to generate desktop apps, as their "Features" list seems to imply.